# Revoked access to data within same institute after moving section

Tags: data

Recently I moved sections within the same institute. All access to data owned by the university has been revoked from me, with an explanation that it contains personal information. Yet, none of this data is tagged personally, due to new data regulations. The closest thing there is to something of the sort is occupancy counts for rooms.

I understand this is a legal issue, but I don't even know where to start with it. Shouldn't the data be usable by another section at the same institute?

Any advice is useful, thanks.

Comment: Their uni, their sections, their rules - you need to speak to the higher-ups about why you need access and the personal data issues. Could you return to the other section if necessary?

Answer (score 4):

> Shouldn't the data be usable by another section at the same institute?

Not automatically, without review.

There are at least two issues. One is that all databases that might have privacy implications should be on a need-to-know basis. Moving around an organization can change what you need to know.

Second, combinations of databases can reveal information that is not stored directly in any of them. An apparently harmless database can help link other data. Letting people keep their old access as they move from section to section increases the risk of someone having a combination of access that has not been properly reviewed.

There is presumably some procedure in your organization for requesting data access. If you still need to access some or all of the data from your old section, use that procedure. If there is no suitable procedure, write up what you need to access and why you need it, and discuss the matter with your supervisor.